# Phonegap FileTransfer 

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

In my android application I want send request to the server and upload the photo. Here is my code

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();

    ft.upload(imageURI,  "http://192.168.1.4:3000/api/upload/", win, fail, options);

}
```

I want also set value on header. For more clearly I want set some codes about it, it is done by Jquery Ajax. I want do similarly on FileTransfer.

```
$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader(KEY1, _key1);
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader(KEY2, _key2);
        }
```

i am wondering could I set some values on header using  FileTransfer()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for setting headers in FileTransfer will be included in the 1.9 release. Expect this to be out near the end of June.

Answer (score 0):

Simon is this functionality in the 1.9.0rc1?  This is something we really need at the moment for uploading images to twitter.