# Basic Authentication with PhoneGap/Cordova FileTransfer

Tags: authentication, cordova

I'm trying to upload files with Cordova to a server that requires authentication with Basic Authentication. How can I set custom http headers in my file transfer?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an Authorization-Header like this:

```
var options = {};
options.headers = {'Authorization': token};
fileTransfer.upload(fileURL, targetURL, win, fail, options);
```

[FileTransfer Doc](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer)

Answer (score 1):

Basic authentication needs to be set in the header and I don't think FileTransfer supports custom headers.

The only way would be to write your own upload plugin. Not too hard to do - you should be able to use the Cordova one as a starting point. Of course the only down-side is that you would need to write a plugin for each platform.

Comment: Custom headers will be supported in v1.9 (to be released end of June). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10915526/245706) answer to another question.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to solve this by including the credentials in the URL, like *http://username:password@url*.

But I do think it strange that Cordova doesn't have support for authentication or custom headers when we live in a world of API:s.